# objc_direct_members not working in Xcode 11.4 beta

Tags: xcode, clang, dispatch

I'm trying to use Clang's new `objc_direct_members` as such:

```
__attribute__((objc_direct_members))
@implementation ViewController
...
@end
```

However, the compiler tells me `warning: 'objc_direct_members' attribute isn't implemented by this Objective-C runtime`. It does this regardless of whether I'm building for arm64 or x86_64. What might be the issue?

And before we get sidetracked by questions like "why would you need objc_direct_members?", I will simply say that there are numerous reasons such as smaller binary size due to less ObjC metadata.

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Comment: I've tried both 13.4 and 13.0 and get the same result

Comment: Then the likely answer is that direct methods are simply not supported yet by Xcode and won't be until they're officially announced as supported. [NSHipster's guess](https://nshipster.com/direct/) is that support will be announced at WWDC 2020, which means they won't be deployable until iOS 14 is released, presumably in September or October.

Comment: Fair enough------

Comment: This works now in Xcode 12, down to iOS 12 at least. Seems to be just a compiler change.

Answer (score 0):

`__attribute__((objc_direct_members))` requires both, support in the compiler and support in the runtime. As the error message tells you, the runtime in the SDK of Xcode 11.4 did not have support for that in the runtime, so the compiler cannot use it as it cannot make that happen all by itself. The LLVM devs add features like this to the compiler but they are not the ones managing the Objective-C runtime, this is done by Apple and only by Apple, unless you want to use an alternative Obj-C runtime but LLVM doesn't have an own one. You cannot use Obj-C at all in clang unless your system provides a runtime for it.

> I will simply say that there are numerous reasons
> such as smaller binary size due to less ObjC metadata.

This is in fact rater neglectable unless your project is tiny. Reasons to use it are rather:

- Way smaller call overhead (as low as calling a C function)
- No exposed symbols for these methods
- No way to accidentally override a "private" method (Obj-C doesn't have private methods, but you can have a method that is not exposed by the interface)
- No way to call private methods

Unfortunately the last one however makes testing these methods impossible from within unit tests.

Comment: I would not say that it's neglectable

Comment: @meisel It's negligible, because on a larger project, other measures will save many times more bytes. Just recompressing a single PNG image can already save more disk space than this option. Even moving a few text strings out of the binary into a file and load them from there on demand can produce a way smaller binary file than this option will. The meta data is basically just the name of the method as a string (which you may want to strip for other reasons) and a tiny description of its call parameters.

Comment: Reduced binary size is cited as one of the primary reasons for doing this by the implementor of this feature: https://twitter.com/pedantcoder/status/1197269246289444864

And looking at different metadata sections myself with `xcrun size`, that's the benefit I see as well. There are other ways to reduce app/binary size, but this is a valid one too.